# Can I associate attributes to the role in wso2?

Tags: java, wso2, user-roles, wso2-identity-server

Is there any way to associate custom attributes with a **Role** in wso2? similar to the way we assign claims for profile.

I understand, we can associate Permissions to the user.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Roles cannot have claims in WSO2 environments. I doubt this is a common requirement. Anything that you are trying to achieve in particular?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not possible to maintain custom attributes with roles. Permissions are always associated to the roles and roles are associated to the user.

Thanks
Isura